# Animated film about giants abducting/eating children, and a girl being rescued by a benevolent older giant

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation, urban-fantasy

I'm not sure if the giants were eating children, or just their dreams. I can't remember any more of the plot.

Some other random vague details I remembered:

- One older giant (somehow) ended up taking care of a girl, in his home
- The giant might have been vegetarian
- I think she was shown to easily fit on his hand (in terms of size-difference)
- Setting wise, the girl was in a "modern" home (1900+?), not in a fantasy or medieval setting
- The giant's home/world was more on the fantasy side
- Of course, there was an ugly evil giant

I can vaguely remember seeing this film in my childhood (1990s), and wondered what it was.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is surely the [BFG](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096866/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2) (The Big Friendly Giant), an animated film released in 1989 based on the [children's story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_BFG) by Roald Dahl.

The older giant takes care of a young orphan girl named Sophie, and takes her from her orphanage to the land of the giants where he lives. There he protects her from the other ugly, brutal giants who live there, who have names like "Butcher's Boy" and "Bloodbottler", and come to our world to eat children. Unlike these other giants, the kindly BFG is vegetarian and considerably smaller and older, and he comes to our world to provide children with dreams.

Here is a  still from the film, showing how Sophie easily fits into his hand:

[image: still from the BFG, showing Sophie on the BFG's hand]

Comment: That was quick! Yes, exactly - it's the one. I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer allows me to :) Now I want to rewatch it and check how much of my memory was wrong.

Comment: Also note that there's the book, this 1989 animated film, and a 2016 live-action film.

Comment: This was only only feature film released by Cosgrove-Hall, the same studio responsible for Danger Mouse, Count Duckula, and many others!